# JavaScript Canvas createPattern

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have problem with canvas `createPattern`. I have two boxes, both will move after pressing a keyarrow:

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/wA73R/1/

The problem is that the box background filled by createPattern also is moving. How to avoid that? Is there any solution? The big box is only an example (`drawImage` is not the good solution for me, I need something that will repeat background image).

Thank you for help

Comment: Worksforme. The background is static, and the box that shows it is moving over it.

Comment: @Bergi I don't know how to explain what I really want :) the box is changing the position, but the background is not the same all the time when the box is moving. So it looks like scrolling background. I want it just like drawImage (but i cant use becouse I need something for irregular shapes).

Comment: So you want to make the fillpattern relatively positioned to the drawn shapes?

Comment: @Bergi I found this simple example to show what I mean: http://jsbin.com/oxuyeq/8/edit . The triangle is just like mine box - the background move when you move the shape. And I want to achive the second, rectangle example - background deosnt move when you move it. Of course I want use my example to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that the box background filled by createPattern also is moving.

Actually your problem is that the background is *not* moving - it is static, while you are drawing your rectangle to different positions.

> How to avoid that?

The pattern will always be drawn at the coordinate origin, whose actual position is defined by the current transformation. In future you will be able to transform the pattern itself with the [`setTransform` method](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-canvaspattern-settransform), but since that currently is not implemented anywhere you instead will have to change the [global transformation matrix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Transformations).

In your case it means, that instead of drawing your rectangle at `x`/`y`, you translate the whole context to `x`/`y` and draw your rectangle at `0`/`0` then:

```
ctx.fillStyle=pattern;
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(boxes[i].x - left , boxes[i].y);
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, boxes[i].width, boxes[i].height);
ctx.restore();
```

([updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wA73R/2/))